# How to Find number of weeks in a month using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to find number of weeks in a month using Javascript?

I have used following code and its giving me wrong answer.

I am passing Month and Year in the following code.

```
var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 0);
var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + lastOfMonth.getDate();
var lastweek = Math.ceil(used / 7);
```

Comment: How do you define a week? No. of weeks are same always in a month if we define a week as of 7 days. However, if you think that week starts on Sunday then you need to consider that. Please clarify.

Comment: Suppose Descember 2016 have 5 weeks, july 2016 has 6 weeks so from my above code I am getting 5 weeks in a july. so I want correct number of weeks of every month using jquery.

Comment: its giving correct count of week, for July it will give 6

Comment: its giving the correct answer, please check again https://jsfiddle.net/e9u1mhet/1/

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with anything? [Anything to do with this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/259693)

Answer (score 0):

```
function week(year, month-number) {

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number-1, 1);
    var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, month_number, 0);

    var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + lastOfMonth.getDate();

    return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
```

or

```
function weekDay() {

    var date = new Date,
        days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
                'Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
        prefixes = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'];

    return prefixes[0 | date.getDate() / 7] + ' ' + days[date.getDay()];

}
weekDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function week(year, monthNumber) {

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(year, monthNumber, 1);
    var lastOfMonth = new Date(year, monthNumber + 1, 0);

    var used = firstOfMonth.getDay() + lastOfMonth.getDate();

    return Math.ceil( used / 7);
}
```